# C++ Sockets Hostname from the server side

Tags: c++, sockets, client, hostname

Hello i've just picked up sockets for the first time and im using this tutorial to learn the basic steps....

http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm

Everything seems to work fine so far, but my problem is im unsure of how to get my hostname to connect to the server from the client. Is there a way i can output the hostname on the server side ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking - you want to "get *my* hostname to connect to the server"...  You shouldn't really need "your" (the client's) hostname to connect to the server, just the *server's* hostname.

Comment: yeah sorry im a little bit confused :S. I mean when i run my client i need to input a hostname, but i have no idea what that hostname is.@EdwardThomson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the client isn't connected to the server until you connect them. So, for the client to discover the identity of the server, you have to use *some other protocol*. The common, simple, case, is of course DNS. You create a DNS entry for myservice.mydomain.com and let the client look it up.

There are other service discovery protocols out there if your client can't 'know a name', such as Bonjour.  The general class of protocol here is described on Wikipedia under

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking

If everyone is on the same machine, then the hostname is the literal string 'localhost', which maps to IP 127.0.0.1.